Login required to view portfolio site on Vercel
I just finished creating my portfolio and deploying it to Vercel. Everything went well, including giving me the production URL but whenever I send the link to someone else, it says they have to login on Vercel to view the portfolio.
I've tried checking the settings for any public or private restrictions but either I can't find it or it's not there at all.
This is the production URL in case it might be of help: https://my-portfolio-js713vf9f-jeffersons-projects-8466c605.vercel.app/

I just tried to access the link and it says that "Team Access Required" . I believe deployment requires team access to view, it means that your project is associated with a team on Vercel, and the project visibility settings are configured to restrict access to team members only. To make your portfolio publicly accessible without requiring team access, you need to adjust the team settings or change the project association.

Inside Vercel Documentation
Here are some specific sections that might be helpful for your situation:
Project Settings
Managing Teams
Deployment Visibility. Try looking into them , you might find the solution.

@RavinaSarda I just fixed it, it was under the deployment protection settings. Thank you very much!!

If you dont need further help please close the question.

Go to your project settings, here in Deployment protection you can find vercel Authentication setting, turn it off, now you are good to go
